# How to return top 2 records when using "where id in"

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have the situation where I have a list of "Calls" and corresponding "Images" linked by a column "CallId".

So I have 3 calls:

- Call, Id 1

  - Image 1
  - Image 2
  - Image 3
  - Image 4
- Call, Id 2

  - Image 5
- Call, Id 3

  - Image 6

So currently I can get all of the Images for these 3 calls by using a Sql `Where Id In` like so:

`Select * from [Images] Where CallId in (1,2,3)`

Now This returns all of the `Images` for the 3 calls, but in my Application I only show `top 2` therefore **is it possible to only return 2 images for each call**.

I have tried:

`Select * from [Images] Where CallId in (1,2,3) Limit 2`

But this only returns 2 images in total I am looking for a maximum of 6 images?

**E.g.**
using my example I want to run some SQL that would return

- Image 1
- Image 2
- Image 5
- Image 6

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `limit`, so I assume you are using SQLite.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are correct. My bad

Comment: I don't understand this question, can you explain more about what you want to limit?

Comment: any two images, or is there an ordering of them?

Comment: @RadimBača there is an ordering to them but I didn't want to overcomplicate the question, but they should be ordered by a column called `[DateTaken]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no window functions in sqlite you need to use self join. This solution assumes that there is an unique `id` for each image and they are sorted according to the `datetaken` attribute (as you mention in comments)

```
select t.callid, t.id
from 
(
  select i1.callid, i1.id, count(*) row_count
  from image i1
  join image i2 on i1.CallId = i2.CallId and 
                   i1.datetaken <= i2.datetaken and
                   i1.callid in (1,2,3)
  group by i1.callid, i1.id
) t
where t.row_count <= 2
```

The above solution find 2 images with the highest `datetaken` value per `callid`. if you need the lowest use `i1.datetaken >= i2.datetaken` instead. The problem may occur if you have images in callid with the same `datetaken` value (this solution correspond to `dense_rank()`). Let me know if this is sufficient. The condition in self-join for `row_number()` would be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

you may Use the Row_Number feature. The below Query will return the top 2 images for each call (*Assuming there is a Colum Called ImgId - Change it to any column you wish to order*)

```
SELECT
  *
  FROM 
  (
SELECT
  SeqNo = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Images] WHERE CallId = i.CallId and ImgId >= I.ImgId ),
  *
  FROM [Images] i
)q
  WHERE SeqNo <3
```

if You need any other count that 2 then just change the Where condition to any number you wish. You Can also use a variable there in order to make it more Dynamic and generic